# Radio buttons are simultaneously checked

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm creating a table with several cell containing Radio buttons.

[PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ap79esRGRtJTpPXJePdW)

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/angular-0.9.13.js" ng:autobind></script>
  <script>
     function MyCntrl() {
        this.list_of_items = ['this', 'that', 'the other'];
        this.foo = {};
      }
  </script>
</head>
<body ng:controller="MyCntrl">
<ul>
  <li ng:repeat="item in list_of_items">
  <input type="radio" value="{{item}}" id="item_{{$index}}" ng-model="$parent.selectedReturn"  name="returnPrice"/>{{item}}
  </li>
</ul>
choice: {{selectedReturn}}
</body>
</html>
```

My problem is when i select radio button the lasted is not unchecked and i not display my value
What's going wrong?

Comment: `angular-0.9.13.js`? it's time to update to `1.3.x`.

Comment: Your angular version is too old and you probably have a newer angular version loaded.

Comment: Angular 1.3.7: http://plnkr.co/edit/75qguMqr981PWbmBjQDB?p=preview